# crontab to move/copy either on specific file or random file at date/time

Tags: cron, at-job

I am bit clueless where to start. I am looking for a solution

a) copy a particular file from folder A/ to B/ @ fix day/time
b) copy a random file from folder A/ to B/  @ fix day/time

Any hint how to start would be really appriciated

CI

Comment: are you writing a virus??? for me I would write a python script and append it is as a crontab I would loop all the files in a list and random an index in folder A and copy it to B

Comment: Not a virus! :-) It´s going to be a random picture + pre-defined message to be displayed on a screen.

Answer (score 1):

Copying a specific file from A to B can be achieved by appending a line to your crontab depending on the time you want it to run. The general syntax will be:

```
minute hour dayOfMonth month dayOfWeek (command to be executed)
```

In your case the command to be executed will be like:

```
cp /path/to/file/to/be/copied /path/to/destination
```

For eg.: If you want to copy the file at 3:35 PM(15:35) on 20th of November then your command will be like

```
35 15 20 11 * cp /path/to/file/to/be/copied /path/to/destination
```

Check out [this wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview) for an excellent explanation on setting up cron jobs.